# Immediate function as default function argument initializer in Clang++

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, consteval

If one uses an immediate function (declared with `consteval`) for default initialization of a global function argument like here

```
consteval int foo() { return 0; }
int bar(int a = foo()) { return a; }
int main() { return bar(); }
```

then Clang compiler issues the error:

```
error: cannot take address of consteval function 'foo' outside of an immediate invocation
int bar(int a = foo()) { return a; }
                ^
```

while other compilers accept the code, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z8h7MPaGx

Is it right to assume that the code is well formed and it is simply a Clang bug? Is there any known workaround for it?

Comment: Indeed, it is known bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48886

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a Clang bug; consider that `std::source_location::current` is consteval and is meant for exactly this usage.

Comment: Thanks. As far as I know, `std::source_location` is not implemented in Clang yet. Do you mean that this bug is the reason for that?

Comment: @Fedor: It’s presumably *one* such reason—that function is very magical in more respects than that, though.